# Django1.10 automatic logout

Tags: django

I have used included codes as shown below for automatic logout after 5 minute.
but i am getting error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

my code

In settings.py

`SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'`

In middleware.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import auth


class AutoLogout:
  def process_request(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated() :
      #Can't log out if not logged in
      return

    try:
        if datetime.now() - request.session['last_touch'] > timedelta( 0, settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60, 0):
            auth.logout(request)
            del request.session['last_touch']
            return
    except KeyError:
        pass

    request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
```

In  settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    .........................
    'app_name.middleware.AutoLogout', 
]
```

## Auto logout delay in minutes

```
AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY = 5  # equivalent to 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the new [middleware syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)?

Something like this:

```
class AutoLogout(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            # Can't log out if not logged in
            return None

        if datetime.now() - request.session['last_touch'] > timedelta( 0, settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60, 0):
            try:
                auth.logout(request)
                del request.session['last_touch']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Comment: no..only chnage i made is     def __call__(self, request, cookies=None):

       # if not request.user.is_authenticated():
       if (self.__cookies != None):
            # Can't log out if not logged in
            return

Comment: its saying AttributeError: 'AutoLogout' object has no attribute '_AutoLogout__cookies'

Comment: i have used cookies to check because for authentication in login i did not use djang.autentication

Comment: That's because you are trying to access `self.__cookies` which doesn't exist! Where did this come from?

Comment: when the user logs in cookie is set..so if cookies exists users have already logged in

Comment: You should access the `cookies` like this: `request.COOKIES`, not `self.__cookies`.

Comment: So i used some other to check if user is already logged in  i get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'streaming'

Comment: After trying my solution (answer) what error do you get?

Comment: Thanks.After using your solution i got KeyError: 'last_touch'